# How to open a specific file or a folder in Android 10?

Tags: android, file, directory, android-10.0

I need to open a specific folder in Android 10, so that only the files inside that folder can be seen in my app.

I have tried this:

```
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                File f = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/MyFolder");
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".provider",f);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,f.getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                intent.setDataAndType(uri,"text/plain");
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

**But, it opens the entire tree.**

What I actually want is to open that folder. The files in the folder should be openable by other apps. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are not alone today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001666/cant-control-the-initial-directory-where-the-saf-ui-should-start

Comment: `The files in the folder should be openable by other apps.` ?? What do you mean by that?

Comment: `so that only the files inside that folder can be seen in my app.` Not possible. The user can always browse to all other locations.

Comment: No .... I meant to say that my app should be able to open only those text files that are inside MyFolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to open a specific folder in Android 10, so that only the files inside that folder can be seen in my app

Sorry, but that is not an option.

The closest thing to what you want [is `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#EXTRA_INITIAL_URI). However:

- It takes a document or tree `Uri` that you obtained previously from the Storage Access Framework, not a `FileProvider` `Uri`; and
- It does not prevent users from navigating elsewhere — it just controls the starting point

Comment: As far as I know, it is allowed in API level 26 and above. What about API 25 and below?

Comment: @SamudraGanguly: Sorry, but I do not know what "it" is in "it is allowed".

Comment: "it" means specifying starting location.

Comment: and can you kindly provide some more help regarding how exactly I can achieve it?

Comment: @SamudraGanguly: "As far as I know, it is allowed in API level 26 and above" -- only in the form of `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate a bit how to use the appropriate uri?

Comment: @SamudraGanguly: Well, in the beginning, you do not have one. So you ask the user to pick something without `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`. When you get the `Uri` of the user's selection, in addition to whatever else you needed to do with it, save a copy of it (e.g., in `SharedPreferences`). Later, when you need to ask the user to pick a different location, you can include that previous `Uri` in `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`.

Comment: To be honest, I am not so familiar with Uri as I am a beginner. I want to make a text editor app (something like notepad). The app will save the texts as .txt files (which I have successfully implemented). Now, I want an **OPEN** button that will open the folder inside which my files are stored. Now, I will definitely want my app to open the folder in which I have saved the files. But I am unable to do it.

Comment: @SamudraGanguly: "Now, I will definitely want my app to open the folder in which I have saved the files" -- if you are looking for system UI to do that, it would only be possible if you asked the user for that folder previously using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.